# CSS Focus Accessible Drop Down via :focus with no JS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, accessibility

I'm trying to create an accessible drop down menu in pure CSS but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

IF the anchor is active I can get the next UL (submenu) but once inside the submenu, focusing the first link, I'm not sure how to tell the anchors parent UL to stay open (submenu to stay open). The previous answers on the stack that I've seen all require javascript to work which I'm trying to avoid (in the case of JS being disabled).

To make the `UL.submenu` show up on focus I could do something like `a:focus + ul` to show the next UL but again, inside I'm not sure what to do, here's my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cq9rxunz/

In my searches I did find another example which works exactly like you'd expect it to but after looking at the code I wasn't sure how it worked exactly. Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cfWpE/

Now all in all I'm trying to achieve this without the use of javascript, any tips / help would be grateful.

Comment: Here's one (*horrible*) approach: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gjx531r4/); shift focus using the tab key, and then use the space-bar to maintain the status while you focus a descendant menu-item. It's horrible, but it's the only non-JavaScript means I'm aware of the prevent the menus from immediately collapsing/hiding again.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that as a method (since it's good for mobile sometimes) but the problem is that you'd then have to click it to make the menu disappear. Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah, hence '*horrible*' =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick of the example you sent is the overflow of floating elements. When you have floating elements and the sum of their outer width is greater than the container inner width the browser 'breaks the line' and some elements go to the 'next line'.

The root link and its submenu fit exactly at their LI parent, until one of them receives a margin-right (this is fired by the :focus pseudo selector):

```
ul.submenu a:hover,
ul.submenu a:focus,
ul.submenu a:active {
    background:#900;
    margin-right:1px;
    color:#fff;
}

ul.menu li.list a.category:hover,
ul.menu li.list a.category:focus,
ul.menu li.list a.category:active {
    margin-right:1px;
    background: black;

}
```

When this happens the submenu is moved to the 'second line' of the root `LI` (below the link).

The submenu is never hidden or `display:none` it's always there but it's above the visible area due to the root LI `margin-top`:

```
ul.menu li.list {
    ...
    margin:-32767px -125px 0px 0px;
    ...
}
```

And the link is visible because it has its own margin-top to fix it's parent one:

```
ul.menu li.list a.category {
    ...
    margin-top:32767px;
    ...
}
```

Besides the hide/show trick, it also uses zIndex to keep the root menu item colored while the submenu is visible.

This is very clever!